# UTM parameters Google Analytics are not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

I just configured the Google Analytics connector with the parameters displayed below:

```
?⁠utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=[Channel]&utm_campaign=[Set per Message]&utm_term=[Link Alias]&utm_content=[Content AssetID]&utm_id=[JourneyID]&sfmc_id=[ContactID]&sfmc_activityid=[ActivityID]
```

But when I send the email the URL when I click in any CTA seems to be wrong:

```
https://www.webpageoftheclient.com/ch-fr/chronolog/order/?cm_ven=ExactTarget&cm_cat=IT+email&cm_pla=All+Subscribers&cm_ite=https%3a%2f%2fwww.webpageoftheclient.com%2fzz-zz%2fchronolog%2forder%2f&cm_lm=myemailaddress&cm_ainfo=&&&&&
```

I also see that when I inspect the element of the CTA the link is well displayed, but once I click it is breakdown like the link above.

All the href of the email are defined like the one below:

```
href="https://www.webpageoftheclient.com/zz-zz/stores/"
```

Comment: Did you try using RedirectTo(@url) inside href instead of just the link ?

Comment: No. Some href are working and others not, and there is no difference between them. I think the problem is not related to the code but something behind. I don't know how those cm_ven, cm_cat, cm_ite, cm_pla... are configured and why are displayed

Comment: Do these emails have to be sent from Journey Builder due to the Google Analytics integration?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to create a case with MC support to enable Web Analytics Connector.
Please refer to this knowledge article as it explains why your links show the way they are with current default behavior.
[How to enable Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000340186&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

&cm_ite=%%LinkName%% - Configured to personalization string %%linkname%% in your case-Descriptive name of a hyperlink, known as the link alias. This string populates with the value of the link's alias or the complete URL if no alias is specified at the link level. This personalization string is only available in use with the web analytics connector. This string allows web analytic programs to identify web activity that initiated from an individual link within the email. Link alias values generated via personalization strings, AMPScript, or SSJS does not reflect in the %%linkname%% value. So make sure to specify Link Alias for all the links when building emails.